# Writing hex data into a file

Tags: python, string, file, binary, hex

I'm trying to write hex data taken from ascii file to a newly created binary file

ascii file example:

```
98 af b7 93 bb 03 bf 8e ae 16 bf 2e 52 43 8b df
4f 4e 5a e4 26 3f ca f7 b1 ab 93 4f 20 bf 0a bf
82 2c dd c5 38 70 17 a0 00 fd 3b fe 3d 53 fc 3b
28 c1 ff 9e a9 28 29 c1 94 d4 54 d4 d4 ff 7b 40
```

my code

```
hexList = []
with open('hexFile.txt', 'r') as hexData:
    line=hexData.readline()
    while line != '':
        line = line.rstrip()
        lineHex = line.split(' ')
        for i in lineHex:
            hexList.append(int(i, 16))
        line = hexData.readline()


with open('test', 'wb') as f:
    for i in hexList:
        f.write(hex(i))
```

Thought `hexList` holds already hex converted data and `f.write(hex(i))` should write these hex data into a file, but python writes it with ascii mode

final output: `0x9f0x2c0x380x590xcd0x110x7c0x590xc90x30xea0x37` which is wrong!

where is the issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`binascii.unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify('9f')
'\x9f'

>>> hex(int('9f', 16))
'0x9f'
```

---

```
import binascii

with open('hexFile.txt') as f, open('test', 'wb') as fout:
    for line in f:
        fout.write(
            binascii.unhexlify(''.join(line.split()))
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

replace:

```
    f.write(hex(i))
```

With:

```
    f.write(chr(i))  # python 2
```

Or,

```
    f.write(bytes((i,))) # python 3
```

#### Explanation

Observe:

```
>>> hex(65)
'0x41'
```

`65` should translate into a single byte but `hex` returns a four character string.  `write` will send all four characters to the file.

By contrast, in python2:

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```

This does what you want: `chr` converts the number `65` to the character single-byte string which is what belongs in a binary file.

In python3, `chr(i)` is replaced by `bytes((i,))`.

Comment: This will not work in Python 3.x, because binary file write expect `bytes` or `bytearray` object, but `chr` returns a `str` object.

Comment: @falsetru Thanks.  The answer is now updated with both py2 and py3 forms.